# Update properties of an object of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose

I have an array of objects and I need to update a few properties of a specific object inside the array and then run the `findAndUpdateById` call on it. I am trying to do this but its not updating and gives me an error of undefined name property. I guess I am not following the right procedure to update an update an object of javascript and because of this i need help.
Here is my array

```
let arr = [
  {
    "_id": "1234",
    "customer": {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
      "address": "123 Caroline Street"
    }
  }  
]
```

Now I am recieving parameter like this that i need to update in my object

```
let ctx = {
  "params": {
      "changeObject": {
        "firstName": "Ali",
        "email": "ali@gmail.com"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need a reference to the right customer... like the `_id`.

Comment: *"I am trying to do this but its not updating and gives me an error of undefined name property."* Please show us that code, and copy and paste the **exact** error you're getting. It's hard to help you with code we can't see, and errors that are only vaguely described. :-)

Comment: Once you identify which object is the one you want to update, you can use Object.assign: `Object.assign(oldObj, newProperties)`

Comment: I am getting the array of object by making `.find` call against _id and there will be only one customer object in the received array

Comment: Is it really just a plain object like that, or is it a MongoDB/Mongoose object or similar? Your mention of `findAndUpdateById` makes me wonder. It matters because sometimes APIs freeze objects, and the way you update things may be more involved.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes you are right i got this from mongoose. Now i need to update it by updating the values that I am receiving as a parameter in my functon. Once I have made the new object with the updated properties I will run the findAndUpdate call

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have updated my code.

Comment: My code gives me a TypeError: Cannot set property 'firstName' of undefined

Comment: The code works for me when I change `changePayload` to `changeObject`. That doesn't correlate with the error you describe however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given: "*I am getting the array of object by making .find call against id and there will be only one customer object in the received array*"

```js
// Given
let arr=[{"_id":"1234","customer":{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","email":"johndoe@gmail.com","address":"123 Caroline Street"}}];
let ctx={"params":{"changeObject":{"lastName":"Ali"}}};

arr[0].customer = Object.assign(arr[0].customer, ctx.params.changeObject);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This does work but what if in `changeObject` object, only a firstName is passed that needs to be changed while all other should remain the same then this code gives an error saying the `lastName` is undefined.

Comment: Did you try it? I changed the answer to reflect you comment - it works perfectly.

Comment: yes i tried it and I keep getting `Cannot set email property of undefined`

Comment: Well now its the email - would you like me to change the answer so only the e-mail get's changed? It will work perfectly that way too. I believe perhaps you are unable to cut-and-paste code correctly?

Comment: It worked now. As you can see in my question I was copying the original array `parcelData` in a `newData` array. I skipped the newData and ran your code directly over `parcelData` array and it worked. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Awesome - glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were using different properties `changePayload` and `changeObject`.

You may want to use the spread operator and map for this as well.

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "_id": "1234",
    "customer": {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
      "address": "123 Caroline Street"
    }
  }  
];

let ctx = {
  "params": {
      "changePayload": {
        "firstName": "Ali",
        "email": "ali@gmail.com"
      }
  }
}

arr = arr.map( data => ({
  ...data, 
  customer: {...data.customer, ...ctx.params.changePayload}
}) );

console.log( arr );
```

*NOTE: This will change all objects in your array, but that is what you were asking for.*

Comment: This also works right. I think you were right there was definitely some kind of typo in my code that I could't see however the solutions I got are far more efficient. thanks for your help